# Linux mint exhibits wifi issues after upgrading kernel to 5.0

Tags: kernel, wifi

After I have upgraded the kernel to 5.0.0-050000-generic, whenever I log in my laptop after it was in standby. The wifi stops working and I need to reboot the system. I would like to downgrade to previous kernel version to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Grub menu at boot to select Advanced Options, then scroll the list to boot to an older kernel.  Once booted into an older kernel, you can use Mint Update Manager, View/Linux kernels to remove the 5.0 kernel